# SymbolInformation containerName use for outline view hierarchy

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a custom language I am trying to get the code outline to work for. I have had some success generating symbols for my language and getting the functions to list on outline view. Now I am trying to get items like variables to show up under the function in outline view. I currently have a flat outline view but my symbols seems to contain the correct `containerName` value.

[image: flat outline view]

[image: symbols]

Here is the code I currently have in `extension.ts`:

```js
'use strict';
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    context.subscriptions.push(vscode.languages.registerDocumentSymbolProvider(
        {language: "as"}, new FooDocumentSymbolProvider()
    ));
}

class FooDocumentSymbolProvider implements vscode.DocumentSymbolProvider {
    public provideDocumentSymbols(document: vscode.TextDocument,token: vscode.CancellationToken): Thenable<vscode.SymbolInformation[]> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var symbols = [];
            var sym = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < document.lineCount; i++) {
                var line = document.lineAt(i);
                if (line.text.startsWith(".PROGRAM")) {
                    var sym = "";
                    symbols.push({
                        name: line.text.substr(9).trimRight(),
                        kind: vscode.SymbolKind.Function,
                        containerName: sym,
                        location: new vscode.Location(document.uri, line.range)
                    })
                    sym = line.text.substr(9).trimRight();
                }
                if (line.text.includes("CALL") && !(line.text.startsWith(".*"))) {
                    symbols.push({
                        name: line.text.substr(0).trimLeft(),
                        kind: vscode.SymbolKind.Module,
                        containerName: sym,
                        location: new vscode.Location(document.uri, line.range)
                    })
                }
            }
            resolve(symbols);
        });
    }
}
```

UPDATE #2:

```js
public provideDocumentSymbols(document: vscode.TextDocument,token: vscode.CancellationToken): Thenable<vscode.DocumentSymbol[]> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var symbols = [];
            var sym = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < document.lineCount; i++) {
                var line = document.lineAt(i);
                if (line.text.startsWith(".PROGRAM")) {
                    var sym = "";
                    var childrens = [];
                    symbols.push({
                        name: line.text.substr(9).trimRight(),
                        kind: vscode.SymbolKind.Function,
                        children: [],
                        range: line.range,
                        detail: "",
                        selectionRange: line.range
                        //location: new vscode.Location(document.uri, line.range)
                    })
                    sym = line.text.substr(9).trimRight();
                }
                if (line.text.includes("CALL") && !(line.text.startsWith(".*"))) {
                    symbols.push({
                        name: line.text.substr(0).trimLeft(),
                        kind: vscode.SymbolKind.Module,
                        children: [],
                        range: line.range,
                        detail: "",
                        selectionRange: line.range
                        //location: new vscode.Location(document.uri, line.range)
                    })
                }
            }
            resolve(symbols);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`containerName` is actually not what's responsible for the hierarchy. It's merely some additional "detail" that's displayed in greyed-out font after the symbol.

The trick is to not use `SymbolInformation` at all, but the more recent [`DocumentSymbol`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DocumentSymbol) API (document symbol providers didn't used to support hierarchies, it was only [added in 1.25](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_25#_document-symbols)). Each `DocumentSymbol` can have an array of [`children`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DocumentSymbol.children), so the hierarchy can be represented quite naturally as a tree.

Comment: Thank you I will try DocumentSymbol instead

Comment: Not sure if I am constructing it properly as I have lost all my symbol information, please see code in update #2.

Comment: I don't see any `resolve()` call in that snippet, or did you just omit that?

Comment: I had just omitted that for some reason.

Comment: Then I don't see an obvious reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Closest thing I could find in the console/log is:
[exthost] [error] TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined

Maybe something up with my range?

Comment: Yeah, if an exception occurs during the call that would certainly explain it.

Comment: Do you know of an example that uses DocumentSymbol? I think it might be the selection range since it would include whitespace. I dont think im reading blank symbols since I only push when I find the Keyword I need.